# Help with highlighting cells green/red if value in previous cell is more or less using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight a cell either green or red based off a previous value entered in the cell above.

I show an example as I am trying to format all my stats to show either green or red:

[image: example here]

Answer (score 1):

Select ColumnH and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=H1>H2
```

with formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Repeat for:

```
=H1<H2
```

For both adjust the range to start at H2.

Since the conditions are exclusive (only ever one or the other) one rule might be sufficient (just 'standard fill' the entire range with the 'other' colour) but then "no change" would be highlighted, which it won't be with the two rules above.